# Cypher query to recursively traverse family tree?

Tags: cypher, redisgraph

Querying a graph database with Cypher, I'm trying to walk an indefinite distance up a tree from a starting node, and return each node with information about that node's relationships.

For example, take a family tree:

[image]

I'd like to start at "James" (node id 4), and get a response with rows for each node along with the edge data defining that node's relationships.

If I do something like:

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[r:Related]-(p2:Person)
WHERE id(p)=4
RETURN p, r, p2
```

I get

[image]

To get rid of the duplicated data, I can collect some of the results like:

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[r:Related]-(p2:Person)
WHERE id(p)=4
RETURN id(p), p, collect(r.relationship), collect(id(p2))
```

gives me

[image]

But I still only have the initial node. How do I expand this to include rows in this format (or something similar) for each node all the way up the tree, including the leaf nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing it by getting all connected to my target, then gathering relationship information with an `optional match`:

```
match (p:Person)<-[*0..]-(p2) 
where id(p)=0
optional match (p2)<-[r]-(p3)
return id(p2), p2.name, collect(r.relationship), collect(id(p3))
```

This query will (I think... still figuring this out):

1. Get all nodes connected at any distance
2. to my target node.
3. Optionally look for relationships on each of those
4. and return the node's id, name, and a collection of relationships and a collection of those relationship targets

This gives me a nice result with only one row per node, with all the info I need about that node and that nodes relationships to other nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to print trees, most of which rely on variable-length traversals like @Vivick described. If you want to print every relationship and intermediate/leaf node on its own row, you can do something like:

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[r:Related*]-(p2:Person)
WHERE id(p)=4
WITH collect(r) AS rels, collect(p2) AS nodes
UNWIND rels AS rel UNWIND nodes 
AS node RETURN rel, node
```

You might also want to use a traversal algorithm to accomplish this. In RedisGraph, this task could be succinctly performed with `algo.BFS`; most graph databases have similar implementations.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to match [variable length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#varlength-rels)

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[r:Related*1..]-(p2:Person)
WHERE id(p)=4 AND id(p) <> id(p2)
RETURN id(p), p, collect(r.relationship), collect(id(p2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This gives me an error: `Type mismatch: expected Any, Map, Node, Relationship, Point, Duration, Date, Time, LocalTime, LocalDateTime or DateTime but was List<Relationship> (line 3, column 26 (offset: 105))
"RETURN id(p), p, collect(r.relationship), collect(id(p2))"`. But even if it didn't, wouldn't this just show me that my starting point is related to all the others? That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for each of those nodes, but also information about each one's direct neighbors.